# How to determine if test has passed or failed for use in TearDown

Tags: c#, testing, nunit, automated-tests

I am trying to find the value that my .Net code uses to alert Visual Studios that a test has failed, passed, or been ignored. I want to be able to use this to determine if a test has passed or failed for basic tracking in our database.

However, short of putting a variable at the end of each test and setting it to "pass", I have no idea how to differentiate between a failed or passed test when running my tear down code.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding what actually runs your test. Selenium doesn't. Selenium doesn't have any setup or teardown methods. This is your testing framework, presumably NUnit. It has setup methods which can be anything, but you chose to plug Selenium methods into them. So NUnit is what runs the tests, it knows whether or not your tests pass or fail. So NUnit is what this concerns, Selenium is nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `TestContext`:

```
// Use the necessary namespace
using NUnit.Framework;

...

[TearDown]
public void TearDown()
{
    if (TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Status == TestStatus.Failed)
    {
        // Your test failed, handle it
    }
}
```

See the documentation [here](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=testContext&r=2.6.3).

Comment: Awesome! I will try this immediately.

Comment: For anyone looking for this in NUnit 3.0+, the correct path is `TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome.Status`. ([doc links](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestContext#result)).